# onblur and onfocus Help - Javascript function alternative

Tags: javascript, select, input, onblur, onfocus

I would like to know how i would replace my onblur / onfocus HTML code with a Javascript function and also perform the same technique to a select option.

Code example:

```
<table>

<tr><td>

 <label  for="firstname">*Firstname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="udetail" id="firstname" value="(e.g. John)" 
     onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='#999'; this.value='(e.g. John)'} 
     {this.style.border='1px #bbb solid'}" onfocus="if (this.value == '(e.g. John)') 
     {this.style.color='#000'; this.value=''}" tabindex="1" />

 </td></tr>



  <tr><td>

     <label for="where">*How did you hear about us:</label>
 <select size="1" name="udetail" id="where" class="input"  
     tabindex="7" />
                                        <option value="blank">Select</option>                        
                                        <option value="ampdj">AMPdj</option>
                                        <option value="bing">Bing</option>
                                        <option value="google">Google</option>                  
                                        <option value="pastfunction">Past function</option>
                                        <option value="recomended">Recomended</option>
                                        <option value="yell">Yell</option>
                                        <option value="other">Other</option>                                            
  </select>                                                                                                                                    

  </td></tr>                      

  </table>
```

Thanks, 
Scott

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using the placeholder attribute instead of writing JavaScript to do it?

Comment: I've just tried using the placeholder attribute but it doesn't perform in the same way as the code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not strictly forced to support old browsers in such minor ui elements, I would recommend using HTML5 placeholder attribute of input tag:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="(e.g. John)" />
```

Comment: Sorry I'm being a little slow... If I were to us the placeholder attribute then it would perform the same task as my original code?

Comment: I'm not sure if its how I've coded it in css or using javascript but the placeholder attribute doesn't perform the same as the onfocus and onblur events as above....

Comment: Looks like you browser does not support placeholder element.
You may consider using some advanced techniques with placeholder and javascript for graceful degradation, but to me you can leave your solution with onblur/onfocus events — it will be the simplest one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments, I have managed to code both onblur & onfoucs events using Javascript functions.... All comments greatly appreciated. Thanks